# how to include a php file,and don't excute it?

Tags: php

there are function a and function b in test.php,which will be called by the parameter of "act" in $_GET,and it have a default value if there is no value of "act"

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['act'])&&$_GET['act']){
     $act=$_GET['act'];
   }else{
     $act='a';
   }
   function a(){
    echo('this is a');      
   }
   function b(){
        echo('this is b');
  }
   $act();
?>
```

if i run the code below,it will call function a and function b in test.php,

```
<?php
   include ("test.php");
   b();
?>
```

how can it just call function b only? i don't want to change the default value of "act",because it will be used by other system
thanks

Comment: I think you might be confused at the difference between an "upvote" and an "acceptance".  To upvote an answer as useful, click the up arrow.  To accept it, click on the hollow checkmark.  You really should diligently try to mark an answer correct for every question you ask unless you really feel that no one adequately answered your question.  This will help your reputation and encourage others to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may define  some variable/constant inside the included file, and when it exists, don't call `$act()`

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['act'])
       &&
      $_GET['act'] 
       && 
      in_array($_GET['act'],array('a','b'))
   ){
     $act=$_GET['act'];
   }else{
     $act='a';
   }
   function a(){
    echo('this is a');      
   }
   function b(){
        echo('this is b');
  }
   if(!defined('FOO')){
     $act();
   }
?>
```

.......

```
<?php
   if(!defined('FOO')){
     define('FOO',true);
   }

   include ("test.php");
   b();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're telling it to call two functions.  When you include("test.php"), the line at the end calls function a:

```
$act();
```

Then in your other source file, you're explicitly calling b():

```
b();
```

You need to remove one of these calls.

By the way, what you're doing is *extremely* dangerous, not sanitizing your input.  As a trivial example, let's say your second source file is called second.php and the user types the following url:

`http://yourserver.com/second.php?act=phpinfo`

They will get a printout out of your Apache installation data, including all modules you have loaded, etc.  There are even more dangerous things they probably could do that I'm not considering off the cuff.  You need an explicit whitelist of legal actions that you actually check and validate against.